# ERROR TypeError: e.addClass is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I'm working with Angular 6 and I've installed a Primeng library to use its full schedule, and then I get this error.

Comment: Judging by the error, `e` is not a jQuery object. Now the question remains exactly what `e` is, but given your lack of code we can't help with that

Comment: this is the first error i get  "ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined ", but after I import  jquery & FullCalenda  I get the Ancient

Comment: I can't change it because it"s loaded from the package?? that's the problem.

Comment: @IsmailWakra I think primeng did a recent update which now causes this problem. I updated my packages and it was working fine before but it doesn't work now. Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `e` is the event of a click or something like that. To select the element on which the event happens, use `e.target`.

See snippet below

```js
$("p").on('click',function(e) {
  $(e.target).addClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
p.clicked {
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click Me</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha` adding this worked for me.

- NPM: `npm i fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha`
- YARN: `yarn add fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha`